# How many failed login attempts should you allow - and in what period of time?

Tags: security, web-applications, brute-force

In order to protect against brute force attacks on the login system, how many failed login attempts should you allow - and in what period of time?

What does it mean to "lock the account" - simply not allowing them to log in (even with a good password)?

Answer (score 3):

I would choose a low number like 3 or 5, and then prompt all login attempts for that **IP address and user account** with a captcha. When the answer a correct catpcha they get another couple of guesses. It is pretty easy for an attacker to obtain a large list of proxy servers. Brute forcing tools like [THC-Hydra](http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra/) make use of proxies.

Things to keep in mind:

1. If you lock user accounts an attacker can use this to lock out the administrator.
2. An attacker may have a list of user names. With some application its easy to enumerate all users by iterating over the user's table primary key. (An example would be the User's profile page.)
3. There are [very common passwords](http://blog.jimmyr.com/Password_analysis_of_databases_that_were_hacked_28_2009.php).

Comment: Can you explain about 'If you lock user accounts an attacker can use this to lock out the administrator.'?

Comment: @frederj  Administrative accounts have predictable names, so an attacker can keep the account locked indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something that should be configurable.  Regardless of what values you select as defaults, a particular attack at some future time may make different values more desirable (at least temporarily).

Comment: Not only being able to switch the default values but as well as being able to check the logs so you could possible identify proxies and blacklist them and if not you could see pattern of ips automating attempts to get password while not breaking your limits and all those other things that can be done while not going under your default ruleset.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in great detail over on [Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/487/485), there are a number of schools of thought.

It definitely seems a good idea not to 'lock' and require manual intervention, as that just leads to Denial of Service attacks, and a need to hire more helpdesk staff.

The incremental delay seems to be valuable - it will break a brute force attempt, but still allow a regular user a few mistakes in typing without ruining his day. For example 5 seconds, 10 seconds, 15 seconds, 30 seconds, 1 minute, 2 minutes, 3 minutes, 5 minutes, 10 minutes still allows someone to get in without having to call for a password reset and is pretty much immune to any normal brute force attack.

Comment: If the user attempts a first time and dont get it, then tries again while the system says something like you are 1 out of X attempts it will get to him that using the recovery password would be an easier option. Do you often lock your online bank password by trying it 3 times or do you stop at the 2nd if u miss it to avoid having to go all the way to the bank to unlock it ?

Comment: @Prix - I don't lock my account. But many people do, hence some of the cost of helpdesk staff!

Answer (score 0):

One method that I've heard of it (but not implemented), was to increase the wait time between each login, and double it.

So after the first failed attempt, make the user wait 1 second, then after that 2 seconds, then 4 seconds, and so on. This way it won't lock a user out after failed attempts, but will stop brute force attempts, since it'll take 2^x (where x is the number of failed attempts) seconds per attempt.

Answer (score -1):

I would allow 5 login attempts per IP address, and then block login attempts from that IP for 15 minutes. 
That would make bruteforcing very diffcult, because changing IP is time expensive.
Do not rely on cookies, because they can be easily manipulated by users or hackers..
I once tried to bruteforce some systems (all on my own website of course) and I'm pretty sure that the way mentioned above is the most secure way. 
BTW isn't it very difficult to wrong-type a password 5 times?

And yes, "locking the account" means not to allow a login, even with a good password.

Comment: No it's not *very* difficult to wrong-type a password 5 times. Am sure I have done it before. Especially when I have just changed my password.